# jQuery Mobile PHP form post returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I see a lot of similar questions on here but nothing exactly like what I am experiencing.

I have a simple contact page on my site that works fine for the desktop version but when I setup up a mobile version using jQuery mobile it just returns undefined when the page is posted.

below is the form followed by the php.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>John's Website | Contact Me</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/menu.js"></script>
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="../favicon.ico"> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<h2>Fill out the form below to contact me.</h2>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" size="40" /><br />
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" size="40" /><br />
<label for="userEmail">Your Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" size="40" /><br />
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br />
<input data-role="none" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
<input data-role="none" type="reset" value="Reset"></input>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="Idont"; // Mysql username 
$password="thinkso"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="john"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="contact"; // Table name

//connect
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//gather vars and sanitize input
$first_name = htmlentities($_POST['firstName']);
$last_name = htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['userEmail']);
$message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);
$date_stamp = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);


if(empty($_POST['firstName']) && empty($_POST['lastName']) &&
empty($_POST['userEmail']) && empty($_POST['message'])){
echo 'You did not fill out all fields. Please go back and enter all info.';
}

//write contents to db.
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (firstName, lastName, email, date, message) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$date_stamp', '$message')";

if(mysql_query($sql)){
$content = "Your message has been sent. /n Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go
back to the home page.";
} else {
$content = mysql_error() . $date_stamp . 'Unable to send your message. Try again
later.';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>John's Website | Contact Me</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<LINK href="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="../favicon.ico"> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">its loaded</div>
<div data-role="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I plan on reworking the code using PDO and a more OO style but the page should work. This is my first time using JQM as well so I think I a missing something because of that.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http

Comment: I dont want you to take this the wrong way but did you read the whole post? I mention that in the last paragraph.

Comment: Also it has nothing to do with the question I asked. The code still works even though it is not a best practice.

Comment: my skin is quite thick, i was simply posting the comment for others..

Comment: ok cool I have seen people be accused of flaming etc for less. I do appreciate your concern though and you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the AJAX function for page loads and it works now just as I suspected. Got to be another reason but this works for now. I do lose the slick transition effects but oh well.

just stick this on each pages head

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxenabled = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works. On my  I added a target="_blank" and it makes it pop up in a new window and I no longer get the undefined error. This is what my code looks like and it works on Chrome for Android fine. It wants a new window to show the HTML the PHP script has generated, including error codes.

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="http://myphpcontactform.php" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score -1):

First you check for the $_POST but you also execute the SQL as well, there is not condition to either stop execution or else this

This is what you have:

```
if( empty($_POST['firstName']) && 
    empty($_POST['lastName']) &&
    empty($_POST['userEmail']) && 
    empty($_POST['message'])) {
    echo 'You did not fill out all fields. Please go back and enter all info.';
}
// continue to execute the script ( SQL Below )
```

This is a suggestion:

```
if( empty($_POST['firstName']) && 
    empty($_POST['lastName']) &&
    empty($_POST['userEmail']) && 
    empty($_POST['message'])) {

    // use $content instead of echo
    $content = 'You did not fill out all fields. Please go back and enter all info.';
}
// Add else condition here
else {
    //write contents to db.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (firstName, lastName, email, date, message) 
    VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$date_stamp', '$message')";

    if(mysql_query($sql)) {
        $content = "Your message has been sent. /n Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to go
back to the home page.";
    } else {
        $content = mysql_error() . $date_stamp . 'Unable to send your message. Try again
later.';
    }
}
```

There are other optimizations you could do but hopefully this solves your problem.

Also you can use Google Chrome with this plugin to mimic a mobile device:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljfpjnehmoiabkefmnjegmpdddgcdnpo

Then open up Chrome developer tools and start the debugging fun!

Comment: You are correct but as I stated in the comment to Mike above I mention that I am going to refactor. This is just me testing out JQM so my question is about that not the PHP. I believe this has something to do with the fact that JQM wants to do an AJAX call to get the new page but as I said I am new to JQM so maybe I am understanding the functionality wrong.